# Why does these data have no change after being processed by gpu?

Tags: c++, debugging, cuda

I take some practice in middle of reading the book *CUDA Programming A Developer's Guide To Parallel Computing with GPUs*. On the chapter 6-*Memory Handling with CUDA* of this book, it implements radix sort algorithm with multithreads based on GPU. I implement this algorithm as blow. But after executing the kernel:

```
gpu_sort<<<num_block_per_grid,num_threads_per_block>>>(gpu_array,NUM_THREAD,NUM_ELEM);
```

The order of cpu_array that takes data from gpu_array has no change(i.e.The order of output data is the same as the order of input data). These functions  **gpu_sort(),copy_data_to_shared(),radix_sort(),merge_array()** are almost copied from the book, thus the problem may be not there. The problem possibly be within **main(void)**. The OS and GPU are Ubuntu 20.04 and 3080Ti respectively.
Any idea would be helpful.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define NUM_ELEM 4096
#define NUM_THREAD 32
typedef unsigned int u32;

__device__ void copy_data_to_shared(const u32 *const data,u32 *const sort_tmp,const u32 num_lists,const u32 num_elements,const u32 tid);
__device__ void radix_sort(u32 *const sort_tmp,const u32 num_lists,const u32 num_elements,const u32 tid,u32 *const sort_tmp_1);
__device__ void merge_array(const u32*const src_arry,u32 *const dest_array,const u32 num_lists,const u32 num_elements,const u32 tid);
//num_lists= the total number of threads provoked to execute the algorithm
__global__ void gpu_sort(u32 *const data,const u32 num_lists,const u32 num_elements){
    const u32 tid=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ u32 sort_tmp[NUM_ELEM];
    __shared__ u32 sort_tmp_1[NUM_ELEM];
    copy_data_to_shared(data,sort_tmp,num_lists,num_elements,tid);
    radix_sort(sort_tmp,num_lists,num_elements,tid,sort_tmp_1);
    merge_array(sort_tmp,data,num_lists,num_elements,tid);
}

__device__ void copy_data_to_shared(
    const u32 *const data,
    u32 *const sort_tmp,
    const u32 num_lists,
    const u32 num_elements,
    const u32 tid){
        for(u32 i=0;i<num_elements;i+=num_lists)
            sort_tmp[i+tid]=data[i+tid];
        __syncthreads();
}

__device__ void radix_sort(
    u32 *const sort_tmp,
    const u32 num_lists,
    const u32 num_elements,
    const u32 tid,
    u32 *const sort_tmp_1){
        for(u32 bit=0;bit<32;bit++){
            const u32 bit_mask=(1<<bit);
            u32 base_cnt_0=0;
            u32 base_cnt_1=0;
            for(u32 i=0;i<num_elements;i+=num_lists){
                const u32 elem=sort_tmp[i+tid];
                if((elem&bit_mask)>0){
                    sort_tmp_1[base_cnt_1+tid]=elem;
                    base_cnt_1+=num_lists;
                }else{
                    sort_tmp[base_cnt_0+tid]=elem;
                    base_cnt_0+=num_lists;
                }
            }
            for(u32 i=0;i<base_cnt_1;i+=num_lists)
                sort_tmp[base_cnt_0+i+tid]=sort_tmp_1[i+tid];
        }
        __syncthreads();
}

__device__ void merge_array(
    const u32*const src_arry,
    u32 *const dest_array,
    const u32 num_lists,
    const u32 num_elements,
    const u32 tid){
        const u32 num_elements_per_list=(num_elements/num_lists);
        __shared__ u32 list_indexes[NUM_THREAD];
        list_indexes[tid]=0;
        __syncthreads();
        for(u32 i=0;i<num_elements;i++){
            __shared__ u32 min_val;
            __shared__ u32 min_tid;
            u32 data;
            if(list_indexes[tid]<num_elements_per_list){
                const u32 src_idx=tid+(list_indexes[tid]*num_lists);
                data=src_arry[src_idx];
            }else
                data=0xFFFFFFFF;
            if(tid==0){
                min_val=0xFFFFFFFF;
                min_tid=0xFFFFFFFF;
            }
            __syncthreads();
            atomicMin(&min_val,data);
            __syncthreads;
            if(min_val==data){
                atomicMin(&min_tid,tid);
            }
            __syncthreads();
            if(tid==min_tid){
                list_indexes[tid]++;
                dest_array[i]=data;
            }
        }
}



int main(void){
    char* file_name="data.txt";
    auto mode=ifstream::in;
    fstream file_stream(file_name,mode);
    vector<u32> vec_data;
    u32 value;
    while(file_stream>>value){
        vec_data.push_back(value);
    }
    u32 cpu_array[NUM_ELEM];
    u32 gpu_array[NUM_ELEM];
    for(u32 i=0;i<NUM_ELEM;i++)
        cpu_array[i]=vec_data[i];
    cudaMalloc((void**)(&gpu_array),NUM_ELEM*sizeof(u32));
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_array,cpu_array,NUM_ELEM*sizeof(u32),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 num_threads_per_block(256,1);
    dim3 num_blocks_per_grid(16,1);
    gpu_sort<<<num_blocks_per_grid,num_threads_per_block>>>(gpu_array,NUM_THREAD,NUM_ELEM);
    u32 clock=100000;
    while(clock--){}
    cudaMemcpy(cpu_array,gpu_array,NUM_ELEM*sizeof(u32),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(gpu_array);
    sort(vec_data.begin(),vec_data.end());
    bool flag=true;
    for(u32 i=0;i<NUM_ELEM;i++)
        if(vec_data[i]!=cpu_array[i])
            flag=false;
    cout << "correct data order" <<endl;
    for(u32 i=0;i<NUM_ELEM;i++)
        cout << vec_data[i]<<" ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "result data order" <<endl;
    for(u32 i=0;i<NUM_ELEM;i++)
        cout << cpu_array[i]<<" ";
    cout << endl;
    if(flag)
        cout << "YES" <<endl;
    else 
        cout << "NO" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add proper cuda error checking and resolve any reported errors.

Comment: Your code cannot be run because file data.txt is missing.

Comment: On my own environment, data.txt does exist.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to always do error checking after each Runtime API. You can use the code below (not originally mine)

```cpp
#define gpuErrchk(DS) { gpuAssert((DS), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(bool deviceSync, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if(deviceSync)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t code = cudaGetLastError();
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}
```

It is not always necessary to put a cudaDeviceSynchronize when checking for errors, however, it's a good practice after kernel launches. If you call gpuErrchk() in multiple parts of your code, you'll see that there's an error in the first cudaMemcpy saying "invalid argument". It's because you must change `u32 gpu_array[NUM_ELEM]` to `u32 *gpu_array` , otherwise the memory will be allocated on the host, not the device. After this error occurs, the kernel won't be launched, either and that's why the output is equal to the input. I tested your code with arbitrary input and didn't get correct answers, anyway.

Comment: After revising the `gpu_array` from array to pointer, I add `gpuErrchk(true);' next to `cudaMemcpy`. It shows that **GPU assert: unknow error cudatest1.cu 125**. Do you have any documents to help me solve this error?

Comment: @Virux I didn't find anything on what this error exactly indicates, so I don't really know. From what I understood, it could be anything. If you're putting the error check after the first cudaMemcpy before the kernel launch, it could probably be due to configuration. e.g. incompatible driver version, although I can't say for sure.